# Is there an annotation in c# that translates to plain text documentation via OData v4

Tags: c#, annotations, odata, data-annotations

I am using odata v4 (System.Web.OData) to provide a rest interface to some code first models.  I am using c# annotations to provide additional information about the models (ranges, required etc) however I would love to be able to add plain text documentation along with some fields that require a comment to explain them.  I cant find an annotation that translates into that.

Any ideas?